# Python XML Parsing with Tag Specific Info

Tags: python, xml, parsing, tree

I have an XML file with a structure like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<title>
  <ch bk="Book1" num="1">
    <ver num="1">ver1 content</ver>
    <ver num="2">ver2 content</ver>
  </ch>
  <ch bk="Book1" num="2">
    <ver num="1">ver1 content</ver>
    <ver num="2">ver2 content</ver>
  </ch>
  <ch bk="Book2" num="1">
    <ver num="1">ver1 content</ver>
    <ver num="2">ver2 content</ver>
  </ch>
</title>
```

Is there a way I can access individual `ver` content for a specific `ch num and book` in python? (for example, access ver num=2 of ch num=2 of bk=Book1)
I've looked at a few xml module classes that parse XML, however they go by tagName, and I don't see where I can input info such as num, bk, and ch.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access an element with a fine [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expression :

#### XPath explained

`//` stands for relative & recursive search

```
'//ch[@num="1"][@bk="Book1"]/ver[@num="1"]'
#  ^      ^        ^           ^      ^
# ch node |        |           |      |
#  + attributes num = 1        |      |
#  + AND Book attribute = 1    |      |
#                           ver node  |
#                           + num attribut = 1
```

#### python code :

```
from lxml import etree
fp = open("/tmp/xml.xml")
tree = etree.parse(fp)
print(tree.xpath('//ch[@num="1"][@bk="Book1"]/ver[@num="1"]/text()')[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach using the Python standard library's `xml.etree.ElementTree`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('yourfile.xml')

def locate(chnum, bk, vernum):
    for ch in tree.findall('ch'):
        if ch.get('num') != chnum: continue
        if ch.get('bk') != bk: continue
        for ver in ch.findall('ver'):
            if ver.get('num') != vernum: continue
            return ver.text
    return None  # no such chapter/book/version combo found
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use xpath to get target tag.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> fp = open("test.html")
>>> tree = etree.parse(fp)
>>> r = tree.xpath('//ch[@num=2][@bk="Book1"]/ver/text()')
>>> r
['ver1 content', 'ver2 content']
```

Answer (score 1):

This way, you can access `ver` as elements.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

tree = etree.ElementTree(file='input.xml')

#inputs
num = '1'
bk = 'Book2'

#list comprehension (assume num and bk is unique for ch)
vers =  [ch.findall('ver') \
         for ch in tree.findall('ch') \
         if ch.attrib['num'] == num and ch.attrib['bk'] == bk][0]

#loop results
for ver in vers:
    print 'num={0} text={1}'.format(ver.attrib['num'], ver.text)
```