# how to search a specific tag in xml file with python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have a very big and complicated xml file which i want to get a `text_body` from it. i need to skip other trees and branches and only get a specific part that they look like this:

```
<req id="1">
    <text_body>
        Upon the USB being plugged in the system shall be able to be deployed and operational in less than 1 minute.
    </text_body>
</req>
<req id="2">
    <text_body>
    The system shall be able to handle 1000 customers logged in concurrently at the same time.
    </text_body>
</req>
<req id="CO-1">
    <text_body>
        Must use a SQL based database. SQL standard is the most widely used database format. Restricting to SQL allows easy of use and compatibility for Web Store.
    </text_body>
</req>
<req id="CO-2">
    <text_body>
        Compatibility is only tested and verified for Microsoft Internet Explorer version 6 and 7, Netscape Communicator Version 4 and 5. Other versions may not be 100&#37; compatible. Also other browsers such as Mozilla or Firefox may not be 100&#37; compatible.
    </text_body>
</req>
<req id="3">
    <text_body>
The system shall adhere to the following hardware requirements:
    <itemize>
        <item>4GB Flash ram chip</item>
        <item>128MB SDRAM</item>
        <item>Intel XScale PXA270 520-MHz chipset</item>
        <item>OS: Apache web server</item>
        <item>Database: MySQL</item>
    </itemize>
    </text_body>
</req>
```

i need to get the string in `text_body` but how can i write my code like 'return string with any id'. as you can see there are different ids. and in last one there is also a itemsize inside `text_body` that i don`t need it. there are similar questions like [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653076/python-xml-parsing-with-tag-specific-info) and [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361331/how-do-i-search-for-a-tag-in-xml-file-using-elementtree-where-i-have-a-certain) i tried to get help from therm but they didn't return what i needed. how can i achieve this?

UPDATE
i need a output like this:
requirment 1: first text_body
requirment 2: seconf text_body

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Please show us what you tried. Don't just say "they didn't return what i needed".

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh  i will update my question right away

Comment: @mzjin i will update my question right away

Comment: There are five `text_body` elements. Do you just want two of them in the output?

Comment: Did you **exactly** copy the code from those two questions? Then they will not "return what i needed" – you need to fill in your own data structure elements.

Comment: @mzjn all of them not only 2. and i think i overwritted the code i was testing so just give me a minute to write it again.

Comment: @usr2564301 no of course not.

Comment: Then you should have shown your not-working code. You must have made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('test.xml').read(), features='lxml')
for text_body in soup.find_all('text_body')[:2]:
    print(text_body.get_text().strip())
```

Output

```
Upon the USB being plugged in the system shall be able to be deployed and operational in less than 1 minute.
The system shall be able to handle 1000 customers logged in concurrently at the same time.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's built-in library for handling `xml` files:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

tree = ET.parse('your/xml_file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
text_body_strings = [x.find('text_body').text for x in root.findall('req')]
```

You might find you'll need to do some text cleaning on `text_body_strings` but that's a different topic.

Documentation on this package can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).